# Calling Async function inside normal function

Tags: typescript, async-await

In Javascript/Typescript, if I am calling an async function inside a normal function. Do I need to make turn normal function into an async function?

Like:

```
function handleLoginSuccess(credentialResponse: any) {

        const fetchMetaInfo = async () => {
            const url = `http://localhost:8080/api/user/metainfo`;
            const requestOptions = {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${credentialResponse.access_token}`,
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                }
            }

            const response = await fetch(url, requestOptions);
            //modifying react states and contexts...
        }

       fetchMetaInfo()


    }
```

Here, does handleLoginSuccess need to be an async function?

Edit: added more functions to provide a bigger picture of what I am doing. Basically just a button that let me log in to google using Oauth2 and modifying some react states and context:

The Button:

```
<button onClick={() => loginGoogle()} className='header--userMenuItem'>Log In</button>
```

And loginGoogle:

```
const loginGoogle = useGoogleLogin({
        onSuccess: codeResponse => handleLoginSuccess(codeResponse)
    })
```

Comment: Except you're not calling an `async` function inside `handleLoginSuccess`.  You're only *defining* an `async` function (called `fetchMetaInfo`) in `handleLoginSuccess`.  Nothing appears to ever call it.  If you *do* call that (or any other) `async` function, then in order to `await` that function `handleLoginSuccess` would need to be `async`.  But if you don't want to `await` it for some reason, or would rather append a `.then()` callback instead, then you don't need `handleLoginSuccess` to be `async`.  It all depends.

Comment: As @David says, it all depends. In the code shown, `fetchMetaInfo` does not return anything, nor is anything assigned to its result. In that case, no, it does not need to be `async`.

Comment: @David Thanks Daivd, if all I am doing is simple modifying so user state after google login, what do you recommend me to do here?

Comment: @user3084686: If nothing needs to `await` the operation and the success/failure of the operation will internally update state in the React component then it's not at all uncommon to perform a "fire and forget" operation like this.  It's a very common pattern in the `useEffect` hook, for example, to invoke an AJAX operation which will update state when it completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing isn't an uncommon pattern at all.  On a technical level, a function only *needs* to be `async` if it internally uses `await`.  Aside from that requirement of the language, for everything else "it depends".

As long as the success/failure of the asynchronous operation is handled, whether or not consuming code needs to observe and `await` a `Promise` is up to the needs of the code and the operation being performed.

It looks like what you're describing is a React component which will update state based on the results of the operation.  In that case it seems likely that the consuming code won't/can't `await` a `Promise` anyway.  Simplifying for illustration, in React it's a common pattern for example to invoke an asynchronous operation in a `useEffect`, and the function passed to `useEffect` *can't* be `async`.

For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async () => {
    const result = await fetch(someUrl);
    const data = await result.json();
    setSomeState(data);
  };
  getData();
}, []);
```

In this case the success of the operation is handled, but not necessarily the failure.  That's easy enough to add though:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await fetch(someUrl);
      const data = await result.json();
      setSomeState(data);
    } catch (error) {
      setSomeErrorState(error);
    }
  };
  getData();
}, []);
```

The `useEffect` operation itself just needs to invoke the asynchronous operation.  That operation internally will handle success/failure and update React state accordingly.  Another common example is event handlers, such as fetching data on the click of a button.  The `onClick` event itself won't be `async` and the browser has no intention to `await` any returned `Promise`.

So there are certainly cases where a synchronous function can and will define and invoke an asynchronous operation.